# rails to postgre connection different between two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A Ubuntu 16.04 installation has 2 users, User A  and User B

User A has a rails 4 application where `username: deploy` is identified in the database.yml file, as well as its password (let's assume `987654321`).

User B has a different rails application (5.2) with the  `user:`deploy`.  When connecting as a postgre superuser and querying`\du`, the deploy shows up with the exact same role attributes when querying form both Ubuntu users.

This second rails application has in database.yml the same password as the application of the other user.

Running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` returns an authentication error

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "deploy"
```

It appears that there is some confusion in connecting between rails and postgresql when connecting as deploy.  (Connecting as another user runs as expected.)

Is it possible that the password be different for postgresql users based on different Ubuntu users?

It is not very clear where the problem actually lies, as postgresql cannot, logically be queried on the user password.  Changing the user password might break the DB connections of the application of Ubuntu User A.

What is the best way out of this conundrum?

Comment: Have you checked that the issue is not due to the DATABASE_URL env variable?

Comment: Yes.  It was not being used, having the database.yml scp'ed straight to server with credentials.